# How to clone topics in mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-phases, mercurial-topics

## Background: Mercurial Topics

Mercurial has a nice feature call [`topics`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/doc/evolution/tutorials/topic-tutorial.html) as part of the [`evolve`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/doc/evolution/index.html) extension.  These act as temporary lightweight local branches, and are an integral part of the [Heptapod workflow](https://heptapod.net/pages/quick-start-guide.html#quick-start-guide), ensuring nice interactions with Git (via [`hg-git`](https://hg-git.github.io/)) for example.  They are enabled by include the following in your `~/.hgrc` file (or per-repo in `.hg/hgrc`):

```
# ~/.hgrc
...

[extensions]
evolve =
topics =
```

As these are designed for local work, when you push, the topics are not pushed to the server (but become temporary branches in git with the [Heptapod workflow](https://heptapod.net/pages/quick-start-guide.html#quick-start-guide)).

## Question

**How can I clone a repo locally to get the topics in my clone?**

Part of the answer is to set the source repo to non-publishing: *(One should probably do this in the cloned repo to after cloning).*

```
# source_repo/.hg/hgrc

[phases]
publish = false
```

This keeps the `draft` phase of the changesets that are part of the topics.

**Update:** With `python==3.9.7`, `mercurial==6.0.1`, and `hg-evolve==10.4.1` or higher, this seems to be sufficient.  As @Craig points out in the comments, the original issue might have been because I was making the first commit a topic, but this is no longer an issue.

## MWE (Old... This seems to work now.)

```sh
mkdir a
cd a
touch A.txt
hg init
hg add A.txt
hg topic "A"
hg commit -m "Initial commit of A"
cat > .hg/hgrc <<EOF
[phases]
publish = false
EOF
cd ..
hg clone a b
```

Now in `a`, there is a topic `A` and the commit is in the draft phase (*shown by orange colour in the output*):

```sh
$ hg log -v
changeset:   0:62c4...    # orange, indicating draft phase
tag:         tip
topic:       A
user:        Michael <...>
date:        Wed ...
files:       A.txt
description:
Initial commit of A
```

while in `b`, everything is the same, including the `draft` phase, but no topic:

```sh
$ hg log -v
changeset:   0:62c4...    # orange, indicating draft phase
tag:         tip
user:        Michael <...>
date:        Wed ...
files:       A.txt
description:
Initial commit of A
```

Comment: what does MnWE mean?

Comment: @StayOnTarget Minimal non-Working Example.

Comment: So this is likely a bug in topics. I do not know that topic was ever intended to be the first. You might want to reach out to the evolve mailing list.

Comment: @Craig Thanks for pointing this out. I can no longer reproduce this bug with `python 3.9.7` and `hg 6.0.1` (and `evolve 10.4.1` and higher).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this was a localized bug.  Making the source repo publishing seems to be enough.

```
# source_repo/.hg/hgrc

[phases]
publish = false
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider this a workaround, perhaps, but it should work.

If you're just working locally, you don't actually have to `clone`. You could just make a full copy of the entire working folder (the folder which contains the `.hg` folder).

Copy it anywhere you want, then when you run Mercurial commands within that path it will behave exactly like it was cloned, *except* it won't see your original as the default publishing repo, but instead the same one as your original. You can obviously change this in the `.hgrc` file if you need to.

Depending on your needs, you might want to do an `hg up null` beforehand to clear all the local working files, which will speed up the copy for a large repo.

Comment: This should work, but will not use hardlinks, potentially resulting in significantly more memory usage.  I really would like to use `clone` if possible.